# htacces URL rewrite redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link: http://testsite.com/api/v2/1
I would like to point my browser to: 1.testsite.com and using redirection in .htaccess link it to this place: http://testsite.com/api/v2/1

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.testsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://testsite.com/api/v2/%1 [L]
```

Comment: I have already these records in my .htaccess: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]